# osmdroid marker based on X and Y, not latitude and longitude

Tags: android, osmdroid

I use osmdroid to display a large image (4096x4096) that is split into tiles.

Now I want to set markers on the map based on the X and Y coordinates **of the image**, not latitude and longitude.

Is it possible to add markers on to map based on this data for example?

- X: 10, Y: 250
- X: 4000, Y: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

Microsoft has written a class (`microsoft.mappoint.TileSystem`) which is capable of doing exactly this.

Code example:

```
GeoPoint geoPoint = TileSystem.PixelXYToLatLong(
    10, // X
    250, // Y
    3, // Level of detail
    null // Reuse
);
```